# Sending foreign key as argument resulting in This Field is Required Error

Tags: django, swagger, pyjwt

I am trying to create an app where Users can login and create tasks. The code for my django app is hosted [here](https://github.com/eadaradhiraj/DjangoJWT)

I am using JWT authentication and drf-yasg to generate swagger. So the TaskSerializer takes 3 arguments

- taskname which is a string
- completion which is a boolean
- username which should point to the user model

My `TaskModel` is as follows

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    taskname=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    completion=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My `TaskSerializer` is

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ['taskname', 'completion', 'username']
```

My `TaskView` is as follows:

```
class TaskView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        if not token:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated!')

        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated!')

        tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(username=payload['username']).all()
        return Response(tasks)

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        request_body=openapi.Schema(
            type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
            properties={
                'taskname': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description='Add taskname'),
                'completion': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_BOOLEAN, description='completion'),
            }
        )
    )
    def post(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        if not token:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated!')

        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated!')
        req_data = {
            "username": User.objects.filter(username=payload['username']).first(),
            "taskname": request.data['taskname'],
            "completion": request.data['completion'],
        }
        print(5*'*', req_data)
        serializer = TaskSerializer(
            data=request.data
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

However, when I create a task I can retrieve the user from the token and I send the post request via swagger to `/task`, I get the following error:

```
{
  "username": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are sending wrong data to serializer.
it should be like:

```
serializer = TaskSerializer(data=req_data)
```

Comment: silly mistake on my part. Thanks